# /arch/setup is not gonna work, why?

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I'm completely new to Linux, the only reason that I'd try it out because I've seen it in a video (Arch Linux) and I liked it. So I downloaded it and loaded it up in a virtual machine (virtualbox). I found alot of tuts for installing it like entering "/arch/setup" in the console.

However, when I entered it, it said that there's no directory like that, so I decided to follow the tutorial on the official website but for me it's like chinese.

So can you link a working, but yet simpler tutorial on installing Arch Linux?

Comment: if it's too complex for you, you should pick a beginner friendly distribution... ubuntu?

Comment: nincs egy olyan ahol leírják hogy mit kell beírni? :D a telepítést nem vágom de a többi dolgot úgy kapizsgálom.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KU1JO5801CY ?

Comment: ez ugyanolyan /arch/setupos, nekem azt írja ki hogy olyan könyvtár nincs.

Comment: This is an international site. Please stick to English for public messages.

Comment: Isn't this a question for Unix&Linux rather than SU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple: check wiki! https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide/Installation

And see the news: http://www.archlinux.org/news/install-media-20120715-released/

> Most notable change is that AIF (the Arch Installation Framework) is no longer included but instead some simple install scripts are provided to aid in the installation process

Comment: I checked a vid. I've a new problem, I don't wanna make a new topic, so: it's stuck on "INIT: cannot execute "/usr/bin/xdm"" and I can't access the console ><

Comment: As I see the video is too old. Do you see this error message AFTER install?

Comment: well basically, I've installed X and SLiM but I couldn't login... so I modified one of the files now I get this (etc/inittab to be exact)

Comment: It would be preferable for you to create a new question for a new problem rather than sort it out in comments over here.

Answer (score 1):

All the various tutorials that you are referring to are outdated. 
Very recently, Arch Linux removed the AIF (Arch Installation Framework) was back in those days, was called using `/arch/setup`.
You can find more information about this from the newspost here:
http://www.archlinux.org/news/install-media-20120715-released/

As a Arch Linux user, let me advise you to read and follow only the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/) for help regarding any usage on Arch Linux. You can always expect the ArchWiki to contain the most detailed and up-to-date help, explanations and guidelines, which on a rolling-release system like Arch is crucial.

Regarding your issue about installation, the new way to install Arch Linux is using the [Arch Linux Install Scripts](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Install_Scripts). A detailed explanation on how to install Arch Linux can be found on the [Beginners Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide) to Installation on the Arch Wiki.